# $P=\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_{k}z^{k}$ if $\forall t\in[k].c_t\in\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\int_{-1}^{1}P^2\leq\pi\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_{k}^{2}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, summation, orthogonal-polynomials

$P=\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_{k}z^{k}$ if $\forall t\in[k].c_t\in\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\int_{-1}^{1}P^2\leq\pi\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_{k}^{2}$
My try:
it's clear that
$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|P(e^{i\theta})|^{2}d\theta=\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_{k}^{2}$
so:
$\int_{-1}^{1}P^{2}\leq2\pi\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_{k}^{2}$
I can't understand why the tighter bound exists

Comment: What is $t$? Please, can you specify this?

Comment: @the_candyman thanks I added.

Comment: Some integrals are over  $[0,2\pi]$ some over $[-1,1]$  ... is it correct or a typo?

Comment: Check this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1508996/42969 or this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3011297/42969.

Comment: This is called the Fejer-Riesz inequality (holds for arbitrary $p$ powers integrals on both sides with constant $1/2$ as RHS is half the square integral of course and for analytic functions in the unit disc that grow slowly enough to be in the respective $p$ Hardy space -not only for polynomials); @Martin gave you links to the solutions so I would mark it as duplicate

Comment: @Conrad: Which one would you consider the better duplicate target?

Comment: @martin https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508996/using-cauchys-integral-theorem-to-prove-a-inequality